# How to convert snake case to normal sentence in Dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub

I found methods to convert normal string to camel case and snake case in dart but I want to implement SnakeCase to normal sentence.

for eg: **myNameIsJohnDoe** to **My name is john doe**

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you please share what you have tried before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it :

1. Using [recase](https://pub.dev/packages/recase) package
2. Using extension methods

```
import 'package:recase/recase.dart';

void main() {
  print("my_name_is_john_doe".sentenceCase); //snake_case to normal sentence;
  print("myNameIsJohnDoe".sentenceCase); //camelCase to normal Sentence;
  print("my_name_is_john_doe".snakeCasetoSentenceCase()); //Other way of converting snake case to Normal Sentence
}

extension StringExtension on String {
  String snakeCasetoSentenceCase() {
    return "${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1)}"
        .replaceAll(RegExp(r'(_|-)+'), ' ');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
My name is john doe
My name is john doe
My name is john doe
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter Only Solution , as [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get/install) does not support pure dart

You can try this :

```
String text = 'myNameIsJohnDoe';

RegExp exp = RegExp(r'(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]');

String result = text.replaceAllMapped(exp, (Match m) => (' ' + m.group(0))).capitalizeFirst;

print('Result : $result');
```

**Output :**

```
 Result : My name is John doe
```

**#UPDATE :**

Installing [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get/install) to use `capitalizeFirst`

```
dependencies:
  get: ^4.1.4
```

Import it , Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
```

Comment: my dart compiler can't seem to find capitalizeFirst
`The getter 'capitalizeFirst' isn't defined for the class 'String'.`

Comment: check the update answer @AmanVerma

Comment: Mind that Safari doesn't support [lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) yet (`?<=`), so that regex won't work in all the browsers if you are using Flutter web.